# Filename stored in binary field in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I've got a binary field and it works fine, but when I download the stored file, it has no extension. I specified 'pdf' extension, but it doesn't seems to work and I don't know why!

Here's the code

```
class exc(osv.osv):
_name = "exc"
_description = "exc"
_columns = {
'imp': fields.many2one('ins.imp', 'Imp'),
'fecha_A': fields.date('Fecha A'),
'fecha_B': fields.date('Fecha B'),
'comentarios': fields.text('Comentarios'),
'comprobante_fname': fields.char('Comp', size=32, readonly=True),
'comprobante': fields.binary(string='Comprobante'), #, filters='*.pdf'),

#agregar scan del certificado real como objeto binario ---- no obligatorio
}

_defaults = {
    'comprobante_fname': 'comprobante.pdf',
}

excepcion()
```

And the XML

```
...
    <field name="comprobante" filename="comprobante_fname" string="Comprobante"/>
...
```

(The filter in the binary field does't work either)

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the file name field "comprobante_fname" on the form?  You can make it `invisible="1"` if you don't want the user to see it.

You can also use a functional field here if you want to add some context to the file name such as **report_customer_abc_feb_2014.pdf**

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt able to connect to Inet, The field is added!, when I want to download the file it says "Download comprobante.pdf", but wen I get the file, the name es excepcion_n (n is the id number) without extension :/

<field name='comprobante_fname' invisible="1"/>
                                            <field name="comprobante" string="Comprobande de excepcion" filename="comprobante_fname"/>